# Mail function can be misused

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST[submit])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];
    $to='s.charancherry22@gmail.com';
    $subject='Feedback on Petro e- lib  Website';
    $message="Name:" .$name. "/ n" ."Wrote the Following:" ."/n/n". $msg;
    $headers="From:".$email;
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)){
        echo"Thankyou You for Sending the  Feedback"
    }
}
```

I have a feedback form in PHP which sends the mail to me when the form is submitted.
I submitted the feedback with my friend's email in it, the mail was recieved to me as sent by him but he didn't.
My problem is this can be misused by putting others' emails.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: No there is no way to prevent it. But in case the mail is serious and needs action by nation legal team, The have all details which computer actually sent the mail so they can track and find but yah no way to secure.

Comment: You can't prevent this.  That's why most websites enforce confirmation upon registration

Answer (score 1):

PHP Mail function allows any email address as from address in headers variable. It won't ask for password of from address.
But you don't worry about misusing, Beacuase it becomes the **spam mail** only.

If the server host name and mail host name is same then only it will be saved to inbox otherwise it will be saved in to spam folder only.

For more reference on Spam : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&expand=5